# Selection from ormlite database table without duplicates

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, ormlite

i am querying a table in my ormlite table which contains value1,value2,value2,value2,value3,value3,value4. i query the table and displays it in a recyclerview. I don't want the same value in the recyclerview twice. This is how am querying the table

```
 list = valueDao.queryForAll();
```

i need the list to just contain value1,value2,value3,value4 removing the duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the values in the same order, something like this:

```
Set<List> set = new HashSet<>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

could work.